My heading structure is not logically nested because my h3 (which appears only in case of obsolete browser) is loaded before my h1
I'm using pa11y-ci and get this error : "The heading structure is not logically nested" which is perfectly understandable since I've got a div with an h3 (which appears in the case of an obsolete browser) loaded before my h1.
Since I failed to :
a) exclude specific rules ('ignore: ["WCAG2AAA.Principle1.Guideline1_3.1_3_1.G141"]' doesn't seem to work)
b) transform this kind of errors in "notice" or warning" and then ignore both.
I would like to know how you handle such an issue? Roughly speaking: how do you inform whether or not the browser used on your website is obsolete?
Here is the code I'm working on:
{% block body %}
   <div class="fr-grid-row hearder-notification fr-mt-2w">
       <div id="nav_obselete" class="d-none fr-alert fr-alert--error">
            <h3 class="fr-alert__title">Erreur : Navigateur obsolète</h3>
            <p>Lorem</p>
       </div>
       {% if XXX %}
         ...
       {% endif %}
   <div id="page-header" class="fr-mt-1w">
       {% block page_title %}{% endblock %}
   </div>


My first thought was to hide this element from my pa11y analysis, but I don't want to miss other issues related to this specific h3 (and this won't resolve my rgaa error). Anyway, shall I ignore this? Remove my h3? Move it down my page? Any advice is appreciated, Thanks !

Opinions differ on whether a document should have multiple h1 or not, but if the tool you are using there would not complain about that, you could simply make it a h1 (and apply additional formatting, if you don't want it to look like your "real" h1.) This note is not actually part of the content structure your document tries to convey, so I think having it as a "stand-alone" h1, "in parallel" to the rest of the content, would be justifiable.

Another option: Just because you want to show this at the top(?), doesn't necessarily mean, it has to be at the beginning of your document. So you could nest it somewhere further down, or even put it completely at the end - and then position it fixed, or maybe use flexbox'/grid's order property.

Why do you want to show an “outdated browser” message? That shouldn’t be your site’s job. Web technologies are inherently backwards compatible, and a quality website would still work and convey the information.

I suggest you should remove that error message as h3 as it's not a logical heading.
In case you marking it as h3 to enhance screen reader UX, you should use aria-live instead so that it's announce that message automatically when it appears on screen.

The thing is, I have to respect the official French government design and I also have to inform the user in case of an outdated browser. I think I will go with the removal of this error and, when requested, transform my h3 into h2, since it seems that the real issue is more about the difference between h1 and h3 than the order. Thanks a lot, @rahulpundir019, @Andy, and @CBroe!
Btw, I solved my other issue: if you want to exclude specific rules in pa11y-ci :

my mistake : "WCAG2AAA.Principle1.Guideline1_3.1_3_1.G141" (as in the
standard) > "[Standard].Principle1.Guideline1_3.1_3_1.G141")
solution  : "WCAG2AAA.Principle1.Guideline1_3.1_3_1_AAA.G141" (as in the report > "Error: The heading structure [...] htmlcs: WCAG2AAA.Principle1.Guideline1_3.1_3_1_AAA.G141")
Hope this would help!

